# Subscribing an User to a Thread using the Slack API

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

This is the first question I ask in quite a few years :-)

I've gotten to play around with the Slack API recently to write up some notification bot.
As part of the bot workflow, I want it to send messages to a channel, where it will create a thread based on the initial message.

This is done already, by using the `chat.postMessage` verb and `thread_ts` attributes. However, messages to threads that an user is not involved or subscribed to will not send any notifications.

My question, is it possible to have a a bot subscribe you to a thread? This is explained [in this Slack KB post](https://slack.com/intl/en-es/help/articles/115000769927-Use-threads-to-organize-discussions-), where you can manually sign in to notifications using the three dotted menu, or by pinging the user.

My initial idea is based on the Block Kit interface, where clicking a button would subscribe you to the channel, providing more visibility than the three dotted menu approach. Is this something feasible?

I haven't found any reference to this on the [Slack API method Reference](https://api.slack.com/methods), but perhaps it's hidden somewhere else.

As a fallback mechanism, I will think on editing the original message with a list of "subscribers" so that they will notified of updates to the thread.

Comment: Appreciation, you have written your question nicely. It is well researched and contains relevant links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already mentioned, there is no publicly available API to subscribe to thread notifications.

 I'll recommend dropping a message to [Slack Support](https://api.slack.com/support) to ask about any private API.

Internally for their client, they use following APIs:

```
https://{{domain}}.slack.com/api/subscriptions.thread.add
https://{{domain}}.slack.com/api/subscriptions.thread.remove
```

I am curious about your fallback mechanism. 
Do you intend to tag relevant parties in the original message?

 You can try to tag them in a reply to the original message, this way the original message remains tidy.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! There are not many intended users, so my initial thought was of modifying the initial message, but if things scale in terms of users, I can "book" a message to ping users who "subscribe". One limitation of this approach is that it mimics the `subscriptions.thread.add`, but there's not analogous for `subscriptions.thread.remove` as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Marking your reply as accepted, because when I asked the Support team at Slack, I basically received your reply. :)

For reference, one of my questions is if there are plans to publicise this API, but there's no schedule for that.